# Store user settings into application folder

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, portability

I'm using setting from my C# application like this:

```
String str = Properties.Settings.Default.SETTINGS_NAME;
```

When I save this settings, a settings file is created on

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Local Settings\Application Data\<comp name>\Keb.exe_Url_pbs4eg1o2ija22omldrwjxhdam0jxxi5\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

Is there a way to change this path to `Application.ExecutablePath\user.config`, and use it next time so my application can be more portable ?

Comment: I can see how it would make your application more "portable", but it would also make it *single-user*. Is that your intent?

Comment: Yes this is what I wont.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using App.config?

Comment: @Mayank OP wants the config file to be portable on multiple computers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control the location of the `user.config` file by creating a custom `SettingsProvider`. Luckily for you, [someone at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/CustomSettingsProvider.aspx) already did that.

See my answer here for all the details: [How to make designer generated .Net application settings portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382617/how-to-make-designer-generated-net-application-settings-portable/2579399#2579399)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be Single user or in other way make the configuration of your application portable i will use a custom config file like an **.ini** file and keep it my app's root folder.

That way any one want to have those settings can just copy it in his own app's root folder on some other computer. When app runs it just loads the settings and behave accordingly.

save data in a fixed format like

```
[setting_name] = [Setting_value]\n
```

or in **XML** file, with Tag name for setting and value for... well... value :)

You can also go with registry setttings but user don't feel it trivial to copy and merge .reg files

This is the way i have seen some PC Games (for eg. i frequently changed Crysis and MassEffect settings) and Softwares save their config files.

Comment: An XML file that can be serialized/deserialized seems like the easiest way to go.

Comment: +1 @alex you're right thats why i have mentioned it.. the ini was suggested because it used by many app already for this very purpose.. but XML is the best choice  many new apps are using it..