# Get list of variables from an Object in a List

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I am using a WinForm or WPF (I believe)

I have a `List<Student> formStudents = new List<Student>();` Student itself, is an Object, and I am trying to populate a combox with all the "types" or "variables" that my Object Student has.

```
new Student() { StudentName = "James", Age = 25, Score = 57 };
```

For this example above, I would try to populate my WinForm ComboBox with values (StudentName, Age, and Score - that I then will search by for results), how can I retrieve those properties from my Object, while it is in a List?

I have tried messing around with IntelliSense (guess and check)  but I have had no luck so far.

EDIT: Just for reference, I am only showing part of the code, but my Student Objects are all already populated within the List. I have checked with a .Count on studentForms. I just need to pull out the variables/types.

Comment: Is this winforms, wpf, webforms, mvc, android, ios, windows phone? Need this information

Comment: @Joe dumb question, I am not entirely sure I selected WPF or WinForm. does this, imply a winform? using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: I would've thought so, but do you have any XAML files in your project?

Comment: No. I am using the drag drop feature for my form (like netbeans). but I have named my variables and such. Does this matter though if I am just need to pull out the variable data? I know how to populate the combobox already.

Comment: If you were using WPF, you can do some nice things with the bindings on the UI (where this logic belongs), but sounds like winforms so this won't apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Reflection;  

var propertyInfos = typeof(Student).GetProperties();
var propnames = new List<string>();

foreach(var prop in propertyInfos){
    propnames.Add(prop.Name)
}
```

Then bind the `propnames` list of strings to your combobox.

Using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

var propertyInfos = typeof(Student).GetProperties();
var propnames = propertyInfos.Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful:
[C# Dynamically Get Variable Names and Values in a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251910/c-sharp-dynamically-get-variable-names-and-values-in-a-class)

In the case above, he's passing the results into a dictionary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In the example here, they are pushing the names of the fields into an array.

```
FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();
```